# Xcode 15's String Catalog always return system language translations

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode15, string-catalog

I'm using the new string catalog feature of Xcode 15 to translate strings in my SwiftUI project (deployment target iOS 16.4+) that supports 2 languages: English and Arabic (I've added Arabic in the info tab in the main project settings).

What I want to do is to force return the user chosen language's translations for the strings regardless to the the system language, so if the user chooses Arabic in the *App Settings* screen, the app should return Arabic translations for all SwiftUI views and other strings (like alert messages for ex.).

This was working fine when I was using the old `Localizable.strings` file and using this modifier in the main `ContentView` of the app:
`.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))` for Arabic or `.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "en"))` for English.

The string catalog works fine with SwiftUI views, but it fails when I use this initializer: `String(localized: "some_string", locale: Locale(identifier: "ar"))` by returning only English translations when iOS system language is English and the user choice is Arabic (the locale modifier is set to Arabic in the main view: `.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))`), and the same happens vice versa for English language. I'm calling the `String(localized:locale:)` initializer to translate some strings in the app that are not placed directly in SwiftUI views, like dynamic alert messages.

I know that I can return language specific translations by choosing *App Language: the language* in the *Info* tab under the *Run* menu in *Scheme* editor, but I want to leave it as is (which's System) to avoid breaking localization in various parts in the app.

Any thoughts on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SPM for the code?

Comment: I don't use SPM